# PSA: Mods can't see who flagged a comment

Tags: discussion, flagging

Somebody recently raised a custom comment flag that said something to the effect of "delete these comments, but not my comment". [Since mods can't see who raises comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236376/), I didn't know which comment was your comment.

I was able to work it out from context in that particular case, but in general, it's good to be aware of this when you're casting custom comment flags.

(Note: when you flag questions or answers, we *can* see who cast the flag.)

Comment: perhaps you should tag that as feature request?

Comment: @Hakase I see no immediate need to do so, unless the comments are cluttering up a question or answer. This doesn't happen very often do it's not that big of an issue to require a feature request.